# How to surround only string with quotations when joining dictionary values using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

i'm practicing on Python and trying to create a class that helps performing database operations, but when inserting to a database here's the code :

```
def Insert(self, **kwargs):
    self.__query.execute("INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({})".format(self.table, ", ".join(kwargs.keys()), ", ".join(str(v) for v in kwargs.values())))
    self.__db.commit()
```

When i ran this code for testing:

```
MyTable.Insert(id=3, name="jack", age=23)
```

I got this error :

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: jack

When i replaced the `execute` command with `print` i got this :

```
INSERT INTO testTbl111 (id, name, age) VALUES (3, jack, 23)
```

I guess `jack` must be surrounded by quotations.

**My question:** is how to surround `jack` with quotation while doing `", ".join(str(v) for v in kwargs.values())` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to try to escape value parameters yourself, instead you want to build the `insert` query and put placeholders (`?` works for sqlite3) for `values` - something like:

```
query = 'INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES({})'.format(self.table, ', '.join(kwargs), ','.join(['?'] * len(kwargs)))
```

Then, use the second method of execute (either on the db object or cursor object) to pass in the values to be substituted - these will automatically be correctly escaped for the database.

```
self.__db.execute(query, list(kwargs.values()))
```

Comment: Thought about putting `?` but didn't know how to achieve that with unknown number of values - clever.